# mx record for a mail sender only server

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record

For configuring the dns for a mail sender server and go trought the antispam policies,

Is it necessary the mx record for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. MX records are only for **mail exchangers**, which a send-only server is not.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to anti-spam policies.

You may also need to look at ensuring you have a PTR DNS entry:

We've come across rejections of our mail service by other users because we migrated to another ISP (new IP Addresses) and didn't get the PTR entry updated fast enough.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup)

> The most common uses of the reverse DNS include:
>
> ... One e-mail anti-spam technique: checking the domain names in the rDNS to see if they are likely from dialup users, dynamically assigned addresses, or other inexpensive internet services. Owners of such IP addresses typically assign them generic rDNS names such as "1-2-3-4-dynamic-ip.example.com." Since the vast majority, but by no means all, of e-mail that originates from these computers is spam, many spam filters refuse e-mail with such rDNS names.

[Basic DNS: PTR records and why you care](http://aplawrence.com/Blog/B961.html)

> You may have come to this because you've been told that you need a PTR record to avoid rejections from sites like AOL and others.
>
> You may have thought that you can add your own PTR record. You usually cannot.
>
> A PTR record (sometimes called a "host PTR record") is what lets someone do a "reverse" DNS lookup - that is, they have your IP address and want to know what your host/domain is.

Answer (score 0):

You need an SPF record, not an MX record.

Answer (score 0):

If you're following John's advice of setting up the SPF record, you may want to check out this wizard. It will walk you through the creation of your SPF record.

http://www.unlocktheinbox.com/spfwizard/

Hope that helps some. Good luck.